# Detecting Apple ID email changes for users using Apple authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, openid-connect

I have implemented Apple authentication on a mobile app and a web app. The first time a user authenticates, Apple sends back information including the email they used as part of the ID token. Subsequent authentications don't send the email address as part of the token.

It is possible for someone to either change the primary email address of their Apple ID, or to add/remove additional email addresses. The problem is that I can't find a way to detect this change - the apple server-to-server notifications don't notify us about these changes, and there doesn't seem to be a way we can obtain that information on iOS without asking the user to manually unlink the app from their Apple ID and then log back in.

Does anyone know of a way to detect these changes?

Comment: You should provide a capability for the user to change their email address in your system. You don't need to know their email address for authentication.